# Proof concerning logs and taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

> Prove that if $n$ is a positive integer and $|x| \leq \dfrac{1}{2}n$
>   then  $(i)\quad n\log\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)=x+Q_{n}(x)$
>   where $(ii)\quad |Q_{n}(x)|\leq\dfrac{|x|^{2}}{n}$
>   and deduce that $(iii)\quad \left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)^n \rightarrow \exp(x)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Now my attempt at the solution;
Using taylor series about 0; we get
$$f(x)=n\log\left(1+\dfrac{0}{n}\right)+\dfrac{1}{\left(1+\dfrac{0}{n}\right)}(x-0)+Q_{n}(x)$$
$$f(x)=0+x+Q_{n}(x)$$ so that answers part (i)
For part (ii) we take the remainder theorem which I think in this case should be
$$Q_{n}(x)=\dfrac{(x-0)^2}{(2+1)!}f^{3}(0)$$
Is this correct , I dont think so , any help to continue the question would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you allowed to expand second term using Taylor expansion?

Answer (score 1):

$2)$ Using the [formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder) for remainder
$$Q_{n}(x) = \frac{x^2}{2!} \cdot \frac{-n}{(n+\xi)^2}  \le 0 \le \frac{x^2}{ 2 n}, \mathrm{ where }, \xi\in \left( -\frac 1 2 n, \frac 1 2 n\right)$$

$3)$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\quad n\log\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)= \lim_{n\to\infty}x+ \frac{|x|^2}{n} = x \\ 
\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( 1 + \frac x n \right)^n = e^x$$

A bit elaboration of $3)$.

Using property of log $ a \log x = \log x^a$, 
$$\implies  \lim_{n\to\infty} \log \left(  \left(1 + \frac x n \right )^n \right) = \log \left( \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1 + \frac x n \right )^n \right) - x$$

Since $e$ and $\log$ are inverse of each other, we take $e^{\mathrm{on \, both\, sides}}$ and get the result.

Comment: Hi,thank you very much for your answer! Just one small question how did you do this step ,it's probably trivial but I don't see it.  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\quad n\log\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n}\right)= \lim_{n\to\infty}x+ \frac{|x|^2}{n} = x \\ $

Comment: @Kimo I elaborated it a bit.